# Scroll collection view after finished editing textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I want to scroll my collection view to the next cell after the user has finished editing a textfield.

My textfield delegate methods are getting called, and I can scroll the collection view at the press of a button, the two combined together don't work though.

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSArray *visibleItems = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
    NSIndexPath *currentItem = [visibleItems objectAtIndex:0];
    NSIndexPath *nextItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentItem.item + 1 inSection:currentItem.section];
    [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to scroll when you you finish editing a textfield than use textFieldDidEndEditing method. 
Try this code...

```
 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
         {
           NSArray *visibleItems = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
        NSIndexPath *currentItem = [visibleItems objectAtIndex:0];
        NSIndexPath *nextItem = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:currentItem.item + 1 inSection:currentItem.section];
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:nextItem atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionRight animated:YES];
        }
```

Comment: @Balázs Vincze you got your output

Comment: you want to move last cell of scrollview when you finish editing in textfield ?

Comment: Yes, there is a textfiled in the first cell, when the user finishes editing that, I want the collection view to scroll to the last cell

Comment: try this code - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

Comment: Why would this work? This would only be called once the scroll view did scroll, however the problem is that it does not scroll!